# How to bind imported ObservableCollection of strings to ItemsControl?

Tags: c#, xaml

I have class which contains  ObservableCollection of strings. and I am importing this class to .CS(c Sharp ) file corresponding to one xaml file. How can i bind imported  ObservableCollection of strings to itemscontrol in the xaml file?
can anyone help me out?

Comment: I would suggest you post your code and XAML so people can see exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: What did you mean by "importing this class to .CS"? Did you mean that you are using this class in some other class?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that we have a class similar to this one:

```
public class Test
{
        public ObservableCollection<string> Data { get; set; }
}
```

Now let's create an instance of this class and use it as a source of data for XAML:

```
namespace WpfApplication
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext  = new Test
                {
                    Data = new ObservableCollection<string> {"1", "2", "3"}
                };
        }
    } 
}
```

Finally, here is an example of *ItemsControl* bound to *Data* property of *Test* class:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication"
        Title="MainWindow">
   <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
   </ItemsControl>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this is not what i wanted I am importing class test in XAML like                             [Import(typeof(Test))]
public Test test { get; set; }                                           and Data will be initialized in Test class only not in xaml, now i want to bind the imported observable strings to ItemsControl

Comment: My XAML doesn't initialize anything. It only binds to Data property of Test class which is initialized in MainWindow class. However, this property can be initialized in the different way. It might be helpful if you show your code.